# Close angular bootstrap modal window from a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal, meanjs

I have a contact form inside my modal window. After successful post request i want to close the [modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) automatically. I am using MEAN.JS

here is my controller

```
angular.module('core').controller('FormCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

 $scope.postMail = function (data) {

    $http.post('/mail', data).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('success');
        //close function....??
      }).

      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      });
 };

}]);//formController ends
```

How can i close my modal after $http.post success?

Comment: Please read the docs that you are linking to. It clearly describes how to close a modal and even provides an example

Comment: Hey but it didn't provide how to close modal in controller :-P
@rmuller

Comment: eh? there is clearly a close method inside a controller in that javascript

Comment: I tried `$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');` but it saying .dismiss in undefined.

Comment: That close method is inside the controller of  $modalInstance not in the main controller that is creating the modal:-P

Comment: I know that, also added `$modalInstance` in my controller but no luck same error `Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined`

Comment: Hey check my answer add $modalStack as dependency in controller then use $modalStack.dismissAll();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got something for you

Use:- `$modalStack`

And then call `$modalStack.dismissAll();`

Simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/53FfeFycrRwHSa1kq4zm?p=preview)

I used `$timeout` in plunkler you can use it anywhere like `$http` :-)

[Doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L287)

Comment: Worked smoothly... :)

Comment: Great have fun with modal;:-)

Answer (score 0):

As crude as it is...

Set the modal as a variable on the scope then just pass it through a function on the template and call `modalVarName.dismiss();`

Comment: Thank you for an answer. It would be beneficial to add a code snippet to illustrate it.

Answer (score -2):

For me using $modalStack gave me injection error even though I injected $modal and $modalStack as dependency. Following worked:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#modal')).modal('hide');
```